# Can't use OpenGL 3.3+ in WSL (Windows 11)

Tags: drivers, nvidia, windows-subsystem-for-linux, opengl

Both of my GPU and CPU support up to OpenGL 4.6 and my drivers are up-to-date. However, my Ubuntu 20.04 on WSL only supports 3.3 . Here's what glxinfo says:

```
glxinfo | grep "OpenGL"
OpenGL vendor string: Microsoft Corporation
OpenGL renderer string: D3D12 (NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3080 Laptop GPU)
OpenGL core profile version string: 3.3 (Core Profile) Mesa 21.2.6
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 3.30
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 3.1 Mesa 21.2.6
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.40
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL extensions:
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.0 Mesa 21.2.6
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.00
OpenGL ES profile extensions:
```

Edit: My kernel version is: 5.10.60.1

Comment: I'm assuming 20.04, but can you confirm your Ubuntu release in WSL?  Just as a heads-up, I'm seeing `OpenGL core profile version string: 4.5 (Core Profile) Mesa 21.2.6` on WSL2/Windows 11 with a 2070.

Comment: Also, what's your kernel release?  `uname -a`

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds IDK what kernel the OP is using, but it's worth noting that [WSL uses a different kernel](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL2-Linux-Kernel) than base Ubuntu.

Comment: @cocomac Absolutely.  It's just that Microsoft regularly updates the WSL2 kernel, and new functionality is turned on each time.  I'm currently on the 5.10.60.1 WSL2 kernel, but there have even been three more recent releases, I see.  Wondering if the OP needs to `wsl --update` to pull a later kernel.

Comment: And just a note -- Ignore my results since I'm apparently not using hardware rendering for some reason -- `OpenGL renderer string: llvmpipe (LLVM 12.0.0, 256 bits)`.

Comment: I've edited my question to include my release.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments, when using software-rendering (LLVM), my results showed the profile was 4.5.

After updating my nVidia drivers (which I hadn't done in a while, apparently), I'm now seeing the same thing as you:

```
OpenGL renderer string: D3D12 (NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2070 SUPER)
OpenGL core profile version string: 3.3 (Core Profile) Mesa 21.2.6
```

However, according to the [Mesa D3D12 page](https://docs.mesa3d.org/drivers/d3d12.html), the driver only supports 3.3, so I believe this is to be expected.

---

Full results:

```
~> glxinfo | grep "OpenGL"

OpenGL vendor string: Microsoft Corporation
OpenGL renderer string: D3D12 (NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2070 SUPER)
OpenGL core profile version string: 3.3 (Core Profile) Mesa 21.2.6
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 3.30
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 3.1 Mesa 21.2.6
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.40
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL extensions:
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.0 Mesa 21.2.6
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.00
OpenGL ES profile extensions:

~> LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=1 glxinfo | grep "OpenGL"

OpenGL vendor string: Mesa/X.org
OpenGL renderer string: llvmpipe (LLVM 12.0.0, 256 bits)
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.5 (Core Profile) Mesa 21.2.6
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.50
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 3.1 Mesa 21.2.6
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.40
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL extensions:
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.2 Mesa 21.2.6
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.20
OpenGL ES profile extensions:
```